# Find string in file and delete two lines after

Tags: string, bash, file, unix, sed

I'm quite new to bash and I'd like to know how to find a string in a file and delete two lines starting from this found string.

My file is formatted like this :

```
username
pass
username2
pass2
username3
pass3
```

And I would like to delete one specific user for example :

```
./deleteftpuser username2
```

And have the file like

```
username
pass
username3
pass3
```

I think I should use sed command but I don't know how should I use it.

Thanks a lot for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/username2/ {N; d}' file.txt
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '/username2/ {np=1; next}; !np {print} np {np=0}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
username
pass
username2
pass2
username3
pass3

% sed '/username2/ {N; d}' file.txt
username
pass
username3
pass3

% awk '/username2/ {np=1; next}; !np {print} np {np=0}' file.txt 
username
pass
username3
pass3
```

Comment: Why are you doing `/.*/`? `/username2/{N;d}` is sufficient.

Comment: @123 Absolutely, didn't know what i was thinking :/

Comment: awk solution can be shortened to `awk '/username2/ || f{ f=!f; next } {print}'`

Comment: Except that I wanted the -i arg instead of -E, this was the perfect solution, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/username2/ { N; d; }' infile
username
pass
username3
pass3
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
username
pass
username2
pass2
username3
pass3

$ sed '/username2/,+1d' ip.txt 
username
pass
username3
pass3
```

This searches for line matching `username2` and then deletes that line plus one line after. Change it to `+2` to delete two lines after and so on

Generic solution with `perl`

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/username2/){ $l = <> foreach(1..1) } else{ print }' ip.txt 
username
pass
username3
pass3

$ perl -ne 'if(/username2/){ $l = <> foreach(1..2) } else{ print }' ip.txt 
username
pass
pass3

$ # can also use: perl -pe 'if(/username2/){ undef $_; <> foreach(1..2) }' ip.txt
```

- If line matches the given pattern, get lines after it as needed.
- Otherwise, print input line

Answer (score 0):

Grep solution-

```
$cat file

 username
 pass
 username2
 pass2
 username3
 pass3

grep -A 1 "username2" file > temp
grep -vf temp file
```

Store the search string and one line after it in file `temp`.
Then get everything else from the file.

Output-

```
username
pass
username3
pass3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another awk solution. `p` is only set if `$0` or `p` is `username2` and `next`occurs in that case:

```
$ awk '($0=="username2" || p=="username2") && p=$0 {next} 1' file
username
pass
username3
pass3
```